# How can I override contrib.auth.LoginView permission?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

how can I override default permission on `contrib.auth.LoginView`?

I am working on a **Django Rest Api** using **DRF**. I am using django's default authentication methods from `django.contrib.auth`.

And the problem is, I can't test login via **Postman**, because I don't have `csrf token`(yes, I am using `SessionAuthenctication`). How am I getting csrf, if I'm not allowed to login?

Comment: That is why you should not use the `LoginView` for a REST API.

Comment: Why not? It supports post requests, and does not have get support. Sounds like what I need :D

Comment: the `LoginView` is made for web requests, not for a REST API.

Comment: See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ for authentications for a REST api.

Comment: Web requests? What's that? Google says it is http request. Isn't rest http?

Comment: I did see that docs. It says that it uses Django's default Session schema. That's how I got to LoginView)

Comment: REST uses HTTP but HTTP is simply a protocol to fetch content. Not all HTTP requests use the REST architecture, and a REST architecture does not per se requires to use HTTP.

Comment: see for example https://www.baeldung.com/cs/rest-vs-http

Comment: You referencing to DRF docs. There it references to CSRF Django page, where it says that I should get it from cookie. And now we are getting back to my question, how am I getting csrf, if I am not getting cookie?

Comment: And also in that docs, it says "Warning: Always use Django's standard login view when creating login pages. This will ensure your login views are properly protected."

Comment: Exactly what I have done...

Comment: login *pages*... For a REST API, you do not render pages. Then you use a REST authentication protocol like JWT for example.

Comment: if you are implementing a REST API, I strongly advise to look at the documentation of the Django REST framework.

Comment: So they say that, I should build entire frontend separately. Entire EXCEPT login page? For login page just switch to MVC mode?

Comment: both the REST API and the Django web pages use MVC as architecture. If you use a browser, then there are extra protective measures that needs to be taken, for example to prevent that JavaScript can perform Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF), for that Django makes use of a cross-site request forgery. For a (REST) API, that is not necessary, since there are no cross-site request forgery attack vectors.

Comment: Then why is there SessionAuthentication in official DRF docs, which tells me to use csrf token? There is even more: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/

Comment: because that is if you are using the API for AJAX. This is when you use a *JavaScript* client in the browser. This depends on how you want to *expose* the API...

Comment: Okay, I wrote a separate view, to pass me that token:DDDD. You were right, now it redirects me to accounts/profile/... That's not what I wanted... Looks like I am trying something different. Thanks.